# Comment dirait-on « Will do! » ou « On it! » pour accepter quelque chose ?

Tags: expressions, traduction, choix-de-mot, oral

Alors en anglais y’a beaucoup de façons d’accepter une requête. *Sure thing*, *got it*, *on it*, *will do*, etc. La seule façon que connais en français c’est « d’accord » mais pour moi c’est trop simple. Qu’est-ce qu’il y a d’autre que je poudrais dire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- oui
- d'accord
- J'arrive
- oui, ça vient
- oui, je vais le faire
- oui, je peux
- Oui, bien sûr ! (casual, among friends, general)
- Ça me va. (casual, among friends, not too informal)
- Je veux bien (casual, among friends)
- Eh bien oui (general)
- Bien…(general)
- Bien (Monsieur/Madame/mademoiselle) (general, employees in services)
- Sans problème (general, employees in shops)
- Mais bien sûr (Monsieur/Madame/mademoiselle). (courteous, also polite employees)
- Tout de suite (Monsieur/Madame/mademoiselle)! (general, employee in services, in shops)

---

- Voudrais-tu venir ici et me dire ce que signifie ces marques ?
  oui ; oui, bien sûr ; oui, j'arrive ; tout de suite
- Une cigarette ?
  oui ; oui, merci ; (oui,) je veux bien
- Pourrais-tu nettoyer les vitres de ces fenêtres ?
  oui ; oui, je le fais ; oui je vais le faire ; tout de suite ; bien sûr ; d'accord
- Le prochain plat, il est prêt ?
  ça vient ; il arrive
- Est-ce que vous voudriez vous joindre à nous et signer cette pétition ?
  oui ; d'accord  ; eh bien oui ; sans problème ; bien ; mais bien sûr
- Nous avons pensé à vous pour  organiser ce travail mais ce serait en heures supplémentaires … Prendrez-vous cette responsabilité ?
  ça me va ; oui, j'accepte
  …

Comment: WOW c’est beaucoup ! merci tellement pour cette réponse merveilleuse, très apprécié !

Comment: Lorsque la requête porte sur une tâche à effectuer les réponses peuvent être :
_je m'en charge_, _je m'en occupe_

Answer (score 3):

> Ok.
>
> Compris.
>
> Ça marche.
>
> Ça roule. (familier)

Answer (score 2):

Je m'en occupe
Je m'en charge.
Pas de souci.
Pas de problème.
Je te fais ça.